# How do I read AFNetworkings Authorization header on the server?

Tags: python, objective-c, ios, security, afnetworking

I'm trying to authenticate on my Python server with the Authorization header that AFNetworking sets. Before I do the request, I set my AFNetworking client like this:

```
// global.globalAFHTTPClient is my AFclient in this case
[global.globalAFHTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:global.userEmail
password:global.password];
```

On the server, I can access the header like this:

```
self.request.headers['Authorization']
```

My question then is, on the server, how do I pull the username and password from the Authorization header? Do I need to decode the Base64 encoding first? Do I treat the header like a dictionary?

Is this the correct way to do it?

```
authorizationHeader = self.request.headers['Authorization']
username = authorizationHeader['username']
password = authorizationHeader['password']
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What does the header actually look like?

Comment: @kindall this is what the header looks like: "Basic KG51bGwpOihndWxsKQ==" What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode it first. In your example you just need to decode "KG51bGwpOihndWxsKQ==". This should decode to a string with the format 'username:password'.

There could be some libraries that could do this for you, but it depends on your server stack.

Comment: The value of the header looks like this: "Basic KG51bGwpOihndWxsKQ=="   So do I need to strip out the "Basic " at the beginning of the string first?

Comment: Yes, 'Basic' just indicates the Authorization method.

Comment: ok, I'm using "authorization = authorizationHeader.split()[1]" before I decode it with "base64.b64decode(authorization)" and now I'm getting "(null):(null)" as the result. Closer but still not right.

Comment: It was my error...looks like my initial values were null. Thanks for your help. I still think it's weird that the word "Basic" is concatenated in front of the Base64 string.